# Windows 7 Search necessary?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, windows-search

The first thing I do when installing Windows 7 is  go to `services.msc` and disable all Windows search related services.  The first time I installed Windows 7, I also went to remove it from `Add / Remove Windows Features` and it gave me a warning which said something like `Programs that rely on this feature will stop working`, so I've since decided to ignore it.

However, I don't use it, and even though it doesn't cost me anything to have that box checked (as far as I know), principle dictates that I should remove this.

As far as I know, I don't have any programs that rely on it, and I don't need to search my computer anyway.   I put things where they belong, and I know where to look for them (in the same way I don't need to index my clothing drawers to find my underwear).

Can anyone confirm whether removing this will in any way, shape, or form cause problems?  And if there were problems,  would they be easily resolvable?
 I'm fairly computer savvy (I'm a web developer by profession).

Comment: test it your own.  remove it and look if you have issues or not.

Comment: @magicandre1981 based on his wording, it seems that it's something he does "everytime" he installs windows. It further seems that he has noticed no downline issues as there were none mentioned of his past experiences. (Male pronouns used for simplicity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the Search feature will remove the search bar from Startmenu, which makes it useless for me. But if you like this it is fine. It will not cause any issues otherwise MS wouldn't provide an option to disable the search.

Comment: That is the type of answer I was hoping for.  Thank you very much.

Comment: ok, use other tools like http://www.voidtools.com/ to have a fast search.

Comment: Perhaps.  I really don't even need a search.  I prefer to use the command line.